# Seaborn/Matplotlib: Plot filtered data on a horizontal barchart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot a horizontal barchart using data that I have selected.

```
average_nightly_prices = df.groupby('neighbourhood_cleansed')['price'].mean()
average_nightly_prices
```

Data:

```
neighbourhood_cleansed
Bijlmer-Centrum                            95.018868
Bijlmer-Oost                              100.268041
Bos en Lommer                             124.242481
Buitenveldert - Zuidas                    148.633065
Centrum-Oost                              174.449275
Centrum-West                              181.870728
De Aker - Nieuw Sloten                    137.437500
De Baarsjes - Oud-West                    148.323816
De Pijp - Rivierenbuurt                   163.523210
Gaasperdam - Driemond                     106.714286
Geuzenveld - Slotermeer                   122.605634
IJburg - Zeeburgereiland                  173.202273
Noord-Oost                                128.538462
Noord-West                                128.862069
Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt    130.387133
Osdorp                                    109.222222
Oud-Noord                                 161.260135
Oud-Oost                                  145.832629
Slotervaart                               119.940048
Watergraafsmeer                           150.214815
Westerpark                                148.807720
Zuid                                      175.561469
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

I need a hand to get this started, so I can add a few details such as error-bars later on.

I've scrolled through the documentation in detail but what puzzles me the most is allocating the data to the axis.

**Question**: when plotting the data to x,y axis, can I implement the filter of data there? To elaborate:

```
sns.barplot(x= df.groupby('neighbourhood_cleansed')....etc
```

Comment: Have you seen https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/part_whole_bars.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the simple `barplot` use.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.barplot(x=average_nightly_prices.index, y=average_nightly_prices.values)
```

Further customization:

##### STEPS

1. Set the `figsize` and required `dpi`:
2. Rotate the `x-ticks` by 90 degrees.
3. Scale the font size of `x-label` and `ticks`
4. Add the value text at the top of the bar plot

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(35, 20),  dpi=100)

ax = sns.barplot(x=average_nightly_prices.index, y=average_nightly_prices.values)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('neighbourhood_cleansed', fontsize=20)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)

for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., height + 3, height, ha="center")
```

##### OUTPUT:

[image]

#### NOTE:

To plot in `horizontal` direction reverse `x&y`:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x = average_nightly_prices.values , y = average_nightly_prices.index)
```

Same kind of Customization on `horizontal` plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
plt.figure(figsize=(35, 20), dpi=100)


ax = sns.barplot(x=average_nightly_prices.values, y=average_nightly_prices.index, palette="Set2")

plt.ylabel('neighbourhood_cleansed', fontsize=20)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)

for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    ax.text(width + 4, p.get_y()+p.get_height()/2.,  width, ha="center")
```

#### FINAL OUTPUT

[image]